# How to use Subversive for team development and code management in Eclipse for Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, version-control, subversive

I used VSS (Visual Source Safe) for C# project code management.

The project was on server locally and each member of the team had a copy on his PC and via VSS we were able to check-in, check-out, and code-merge easily.

Is it possible for Android project to be managed like VSS using "Subversive" plugin for Eclipse IDE? Eventually, I installed the plug-in and started to deal with it.

If not what is the best tool or plug-in to do this?

Appreciate your help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

*Subversive* works with Apache Subversion only.

As far as I know there is no good Visual SourceSafe plug-in for Eclipse IDE.  I'm aware of [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vssplugin/), however didn't try.

I can agree with the @Romiox suggestion. 
Move to Apache Subversion if you can. TortoiseSVN is great client implemented as a Windows Shell extension and you could also use Subversive or Subclipse plug-ins.

Reference: The [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and [TortoiseSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/support.html).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use the subversive plug-in myself (for Subversion repositories, though), and couldn't figure out how to get it to integrate into the existing environment (It didn't recognize the repository, and I couldn't find a way to tell it that there was one).

If you're very flexible in your code management, try [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/). The [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) client integrates into Windows easily, and it's super useful as well as super simple to use, and provides the features you need (check-in (called 'commit' in svn), check-out, update, diff for merging and more).

Also, there are lot services on the internet which provide repository servers (shared hosting). When I wanted to get familiar with source management, I set up an account at assembla.com, they offer a free repository for unlimited members with up to 1GB of storage. You might want to try that.

Comment: Oh, and if you DO migrate, you may as well migrate your C# Code Management. For VS2010 there is a plugin called AnkhSVN (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) which integrates beautifully. I'm quite sure though, that you can't use plugins in the Express Version, but you're probably using one for VSS so I guess that isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, and about creating local repository via Subversive, you have to install Native JavaHL connector and don't use SVN Kit.

Comment: @Romiox BTW VisualSVN 3.0 (http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) has a new **free community license** and IMHO VisualSVN integrates much better than AnkhSVN.

Comment: @Amt87 I do have the connector, and creating wasn't my problem. I had already used TortoiseSVN to push my code to the server for backup and thus, I had a repository. I just wanted to use it from within Eclipse. Probably being spoiled from AnkhSVN, I expected that the plugin would figure out stuff by itself, which it didn't, and just telling it that it already stood knee-deep in a repository was the thing that I couldn't figure out how to do (granted, I went back to Tortoise after the first few tries, and did not dig through docus and such).
(@)bahrep Thanks, I'll try it eventually.